# Which MSDTC is the transaction manager?

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

Having a distributed transaction over 2 SQL Server databases, which MSDTC will be chosen to be the transaction manager?

Comment: How many MSDTC are involved? *2 SQL Server databases* can exist on the same instance and 0 MSDTC will be involved.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction manager is the SQL Server that initiated the distributed transaction so the first one. However, this isn't strongly documented so the best is to check, which one is currently :

From MSDN : "Using the MS DTC Transaction List and Transaction Properties Windows" on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755087(v=ws.10).aspx

> When you right-click a transaction in the Transaction List dialog box
>   and then click Properties, the Transaction Properties dialog box
>   opens. It displays a Parent/Subordinate column and an ID column. The
>   Parent/Subordinate column displays the name of the parent transaction
>   manager, if any, ...

To show that dialog, go to Administrative Tools / Component Services / Component Services / Computers / My Computer / Distributed Transaction Coordinator / Local DTC / Transaction List

I hope it helps.